# @Findby vs. By cons and pros?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, factory-pattern

I started a PageFactory framework and started using `@FindBy` without really knowing much about it, besides reading that this was an advanced method.

What I realized is `ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated` does not work with `WebElements`. So i had to use `.visibilityOf` which is not the same, and sometimes it won't perform actions on my elements.

So I changed it to a By method and now the locators work perfectly fine again.

Is the `By` class is more robust for storing elements?

Which would be less problem prone? `@Findby` or `By`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@FindBy` attribute is very helpful for static elements. The elements that are not loaded dynamically can easily be mapped in a cleaner way using `@FindBy` attribute. You are using Expected conditions because the elements are not loaded instantly and Selenium needs to wait for the element to load or do a regular check for it's existence. In that cases, `@FindBy` would not work and you have to use `By` selectors. In such case I create private fields in order to reduce code duplications. 
As per my knowledge, using `@FindBy` is a cleaner way for element mapping in page Object Pattern which is not possible to use in every scenario and that's the only benefit of using that.

**Example of how private field can be used for elements mapping**

```
private static readonly By TestSelector = By.XPath("Your xpath");

public void ClickUpdate()
{
    //Use same selector/field
    Driver.FindElement(TestSelector).Click();
}

public void ClickUpdate2()
{
    //Use same selector/field
    Driver.FindElement(TestSelector).Click();    
}
```

*Note: C# code*

Comment: Thanks very helpful, can you show me a code example of your private fields, would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: Also, is there a way to create a function that would allow you to accept WebElement using .presenceOfElementLocated(WebElement) <----How can i make something like this?

Comment: There are couple of method overloading present in `ExpectedCondtions` that accepts WebElements but not all. Such as in `visibilityOf` you can pass `WebElement`. See a full list [here](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html). Hope this helps

Comment: Yes I know, but 'visibilityOf' was what i was having issues with. Do you know if visibilityOf and '.presenceOfElementLocated' operate the same? As I mentioned 'ElementLocated' constantly works whereas 'visibilityOf' doesn't all the time. That was why I wanted to make 'ElementLocated' accept WebElements.

Comment: There are not. There are scenarios when you want to know if element exist not necessarily visible. You can create your custom method to do that. I would see if I can give you some info on that

Comment: Yes i just read the link you provided, visibility checks that it's in DOM and showing visible, whereas present is just looking that it's present in the DOM. Creating a custom ExpectedFunction would be very useful as then I can keep the @Findby method, and have the functionality that By provides.

Comment: Also, is there a way to save @Findby as By instead of a WebElement?

Answer (score 0):

I just did two examples. First with annotation and second one without. 
There are the differences. If the constructor for page is called `PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);` it checks all the elements on page. If some of them is not there, it fails (dynamic page) regardless if the element is necessary for a given test. Next problem is the failing test. It is not easily identifiable the place where it fails. it shows the page, but exact place from stack trace is not there. 
In the second example, you can easily find the method (place) where it fails. And also, the elements that are not called and could be missing do not cause the test to be failed unless the missing/wrong element is called.

With annotation

```
@FindBy(id = "lst-ib")
private WebElement searchField;

@FindBy(css = "input[name=\"btnK\"]")
private WebElement searchButton;
```

and without

```
private static final String SEARCH_FIELD_ID = "lst-ib";
private static final String SEARCH_BUTTON_CSS = "input[name=\"btnK\"]";
```

In the first example, it is called more easily e.g.

```
public void clickToSearchButton(){
searchButton.click();
}
```

Whereas in the second example:

```
public void clickToSearchButton(){
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(SEARCH_BUTTON_CSS)).click();
}
```